# Form edit is blanking out my entries

Tags: php, sql

So I've got a form to edit entries which is populating with what has already been entered from the database.  When I make an edit, it is saving and redirecting me back to the listing page with no errors, but it's not changing anything.  I'm guessing it's getting confused as to where to pull the values from.

This is the the SQL Query to populate the form with the values (this part works):

```
    <?php

// query db
$gigid = $_GET['gigid'];
$con = mysqli_connect("***********","***********","***********","***********");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM gigs WHERE gigid=$gigid") or die(mysqli_error()); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
mysqli_close($con);

// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
if($row)
{
// get data from db
        $gig_name = $row['gig_name'];
        $gig_type = $row['gig_type'];
        $gig_date = $row['gig_date'];
        $gig_customer = $row['gig_customer'];
        $gig_venue = $row['venue_name'];
        $gig_fee = $row['gig_fee'];
        $gig_status = $row['gig_status'];   
 }
 ?>
```

This is an excerpt from the form:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="create-ticket" method='post' action='edit_gig_process.php?       gigid=<?php echo $_GET['gigid']; ?>'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Edit Gig Information</legend>

        <input type="hidden" class="input-xxlarge" id="gig_date_created" name="gig_date_created">
        <input type="hidden" class="input-xxlarge" id="userid" name="userid">

<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="gigid">Gig ID</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="gigid" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $_GET['gigid']; ?>"      />
      </div>
</div>  

<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="gig_name">Gig Name (Required)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="gig_name" value="<?php echo        $row['gig_name']; ?>" name="gig_name">

      </div>
</div>
```

This is an excerpt from the update query:

```
$gigid = $_GET['gigid'];

  $sql= "UPDATE gigs set 
  gig_name='$gig_name',
  gig_type='$gig_type', 
  gig_customer='$gig_customer', 
  gig_date='$gig_date_created', 
  gig_start_time='$gig_start_time', 
  gig_end_time='$gig_end_time',     
  gig_fee='$gig_fee', 
  gig_status='$gig_status', 
  venue_name='$venue_name', 
  venue_address='$venue_address', 
  venue_contact='$venue_contact',
  WHERE 
  gigid='$gigid'";

  header('Location: http://managegigs.com/cp/my-gigs.php');

  mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `echo $sql` and `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's going on behind the scenes? And note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I'm a newbie.  Also, I'll worry about security once it works.

Comment: bad attitude. start secure. if you leave it for later, "later" will never come.

Comment: You are not running a update query, the update is just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not running a update query, your update is just a string.

After

```
$sql= "UPDATE gigs set 

  gig_name='$gig_name',
  gig_type='$gig_type', 
  gig_customer='$gig_customer', 
  gig_date='$gig_date_created', 
  gig_start_time='$gig_start_time', 
  gig_end_time='$gig_end_time',     
  gig_fee='$gig_fee', 
  gig_status='$gig_status', 
  venue_name='$venue_name', 
  venue_address='$venue_address', 
  venue_contact='$venue_contact'
  WHERE 
  gigid='$gigid'";
```

add:

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

also, at least change this:

```
$gigid = $_GET['gigid'];
```

add:

```
$gigid = mysqli_real_escape_string($gigid);
```

directly after to have it a little secured. Putting $_GET directly to DB is dangerous.

**Uploadpart in complete:**

```
$gig_name = $_POST['gig_name'];
// fetch all $_POST(ed) data
// and secure with
$gig_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$gig_name);


$gigid = $_GET['gigid'];
$gigid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$gigid);
  $sql= "UPDATE gigs set 
  gig_name='$gig_name',
  gig_type='$gig_type', 
  gig_customer='$gig_customer', 
  gig_date='$gig_date_created', 
  gig_start_time='$gig_start_time', 
  gig_end_time='$gig_end_time',     
  gig_fee='$gig_fee', 
  gig_status='$gig_status', 
  venue_name='$venue_name', 
  venue_address='$venue_address', 
  venue_contact='$venue_contact'
  WHERE 
  gigid='$gigid'";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  header('Location: http://managegigs.com/cp/my-gigs.php');

  mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Try to copy the edited answer, should at least update gig_name

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']' in /******/edit_gig_process.php on line 25

(which is)  $gigid = $_GET['gigid'];

Comment: The line is correct. I had forgotten one ' in $gig_name = $_POST['gig_name'];, but it's allready in. Can you compare this line and make sure it looks like above, not like ['gig_name];

Comment: It didn't seem to update.  To test that it knows the value, I echo'd $gig_name and $gigid and removed the redirect and it displayed the values just fine.

Comment: But you are connecting to the database within the upload file, right?

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect("***********","***********","***********","***********");
is above your code?

Comment: Yep.  I threw this in and it says "connected"

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "Connected";
}

Comment: Please add this: or die(mysqli_error($con)); to mysqli_query($con,$sql); => mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

Comment: Found the error. There was a , too much here:  venue_contact='$venue_contact' (last line of update string), changed it in my code